# Design a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Design a double integral whose value is the same as $\int^1_0 \sin\sqrt x\,dx$

How do I design that double integral. Is it something related to change of polar coordinate?

Comment: $\iint_S dS$ gives you the area of the surface S. $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ gives you the area under the graph of $f(x)$ between a and b. Try to relate this two ideas, remember that $\sin (\sqrt x)$ is positive between 0 and 1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Given any function $f(x),$ what is $$\int_0^{f(x)}1\,dy?$$

Answer (score 1):

For example we can write:

$$\int_0^1\sin(\sqrt{x})\, dx=\int_0^1\int_0^x \frac{\cos(\sqrt{t})}{2\sqrt{t}}dtdx$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Cameron's solution.

**Hint:** Given any $f(x)$, what is

$$\large \int^x_0 f'(t) dt$$

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, I did mean that. Editing. Bad choice of notation on my part